# Alternative to positive lookbehind for MS Word

Tags: sql, ms-word, wildcard

I have a Word document with improperly formatted SQL exported from Access. I am trying to add double quotes around columns that are renamed with the AS keyword.

```
SELECT ID_NO,
   Sum(QTY) AS Qty,
   '8500' AS Acct Number, 
   Sum(AMOUNT) AS 07_STD_Xtnd
FROM ...
```

Should be:

```
SELECT ID_NO,
   Sum(QTY) AS "Qty",
   '8500' AS "Acct Number", 
   Sum(AMOUNT) AS "07_STD_Xtnd"
FROM ...
```

I was able to write this RegEx that matches the column names using positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\sas\s)(.*?)(?=[,\r\n])
```

https://regex101.com/r/LwCZZ5/1

In Word, positive lookbehind apparently doesn't work. How can I rewrite this without positive lookbehind?

Comment: You can use this pattern: `(AS\s+)(.*?)(?=[,\n\r])` and replacement string: `\1"\2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for this. A simple *wildcard* Find/Replace in Word can do it:

Find = ( AS )(*)([,^13^l])

Replace = \1^34\2^34\3

Answer (score 0):

@macropod's answer is perfect. Here are my notes from my code explaining what these mean. Note that I dropped out the "^l", which indicates a manual line break in Word via Shift+Enter. In my case, the line breaks were inserted through code as ^p.

```
    'Find pattern: "( AS )(*)([,^13])"
    '( ) in the find pattern is a group of matching characters. There are three groups in the find pattern.
    'Group 1 ( AS )     is the literal text " AS "
    'Group 2 (*)        is the column name, "My column name"
    'Group 3 ([,^13])   is any of the characters listed within the square brackets.
    '                   A comma or ^13, which is a carriage return Chr(13).
    'Replace pattern: "\1^34\2^34\3"
    'The three groups from the find pattern are used in the replace pattern.
    'Group 1 is indicated by \1, group 2 by \2, and group 3 by \3
    '^34 is a double quote character " Chr(34)
    'Thus, the replace pattern is (Group 1)"(Group 2)"(Group 3) or <space>AS "My column name"<comma or carriage return>
```